# How to plot monthly data of Individual year on the same plot correctly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some sales data of a store of some certain years and I want to plot its monthly sales data.
Here I had DateTime object so through this I plotted like this

```py
wlmrt['Date'].dt.month.value_counts().sort_index().plot()
# Here it's output actually it's output is graph but to show its error I am showing it's value
1     450
2     495
3     540
4     630
5     585
6     540
7     585
8     540
9     585
10    585
11    405
12    495
```

I think it groups the same month of different year and plot that but I want the sales data of each month of each year to be plotted

Comment: [Resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) by month then plot.

Comment: Did the code in my answer give you the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
wlmrt['Date'].resample('M').count().plot()
```

Should do the trick. [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)  is a "*convenience method for frequency conversion and resampling*", the `count()` method of the returned `Resampler` object generates counts for each resampled period as a `DataFrame` which can then be plotted using the typical `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` method.

Comment: Actually I converted that date object through pandas method to-datetime and your answer works in it